How to insert full precision decimal values into clickhouse?
The long precision values are getting truncated even after using Decimal() type in clickhouse. How to fix this?
For example the value 5914.922286612016543134 is truncated and inserted as 5914.922286612016.
this is how I create the table
CREATE TABLE db.high_precision_table
(
    id UInt32,
    high_precision_value Decimal(72, 38)
) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree()
ORDER BY id
SETTINGS allow_nullable_key = 1, index_granularity = 8192;

I am not sure with alternative workaround, we are in need of exact precision in crypto systems.
Let me know how to fix this, thanks.

Probably the issue is not on ClickHouse side, look at this query select 5914.922286612016543134 n, toDecimal64(n, 12) n2, CAST(n AS Decimal(72, 38)) n3.

I get the same 5914.922286612016 in all n, n2, n3.

you should input as string (not toString)
SELECT toDecimal128('5914.922286612016543134', 18)

